# How to specify container arguments when creating VM from container image in GCP

Tags: containers, gcp

GCP VMs can be created using a container image. The form on GCP console has text boxes to enter the `Command` and `Arguments`. What is not clear is how to specify the arguments.

The corresponding `docker run` command is like so

```
docker run \
    --network=host \
    gcr.io/cloud-healthcare-containers/mllp-adapter \
    /usr/mllp_adapter/mllp_adapter \
    --hl7_v2_project_id=<PROJECT_ID> \
    --hl7_v2_location_id=<LOCATION_ID> \
    --hl7_v2_dataset_id=<DATASET_ID> \
    --hl7_v2_store_id=<STORE_ID> \
    --export_stats=false \
    --receiver_ip=127.0.0.1 --port 2575 \
    --mllp_addr=127.0.0.1:2525 \
    --api_addr_prefix=https://healthcare.googleapis.com:443/v1 \
    --logtostderr
```

In the textboxes do I enter
`--hl7_v2_store_id=<STORE_ID>`
or
`hl7_v2_store_id=<STORE_ID>`
or
`"--hl7_v2_store_id=<STORE_ID>"`

None of the options seem to work.

SSHing to the created container and running

`sudo journalctl -u konlet-startup`

displays the log but there are no error messages and the container doesnt seem to be responding. Also `/usr/mllp_adapter` folder is not present.